# Office 365 Management APIs notification data ClientIP is null

Tags: office365

After subscribe a webhook, I got notification data with "null" ClientIP, and it's operation is "Add user. ", "Delete user." and "Update user.". Is it correct? Does the ClientIP should be xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?

Answer (score 0):

According to my search, the clientIP should be xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

Here is a sample response of [Add user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#retrieving-content), it shows that clientIP should format as:

```
"ClientIP": "134.170.188.221"
```

Comment: Yes, it should be like "134.170.188.221", but I got "ClientIP" : null from notification data.